AWS SQS – failed message clogs queue
I have a long running-task (10 minutes) executed via a lambda function. The visibility timeout for my (Standard) SQS queue is set to 15 minutes and the lambda event source for the queue has a max concurrency of 2, no retries (neither on the queue level nor the lambda). The batch size is set to 1.
My problem: If I have a bug in my code, the lambda fails immediately, but the queue is clogged for the whole 15 minutes. I don't understand why.
My (apparently wrong) understanding: A failed lambda invocation would signal to the SQS that the message could not be processed, so the message would be sent to the configured DLQ and the next message would be processed immediately.
My question: How can I achieve, that in case of an error in my processing lambda function, the queue proceeds with the next message immediately instead of waiting for the message timeout to complete?

Are you using a FIFO queue or a Standard queue? If you are using a FIFO queue, do all messages have the same Message Group ID? In your DLQ configuration -- after how many retries will it send messages to the DLQ? (You mentioned 'no retries' but I couldn't figure out whether that was related to the Event Source or the Lambda function.)

I edited for clarification. No retries on the queue nor lambda level. I'm using a standard queue.

How many messages do you have in the queue? Are there more than 2 messages at the time that one fails?

As soon as a third message arrives in the queue, I experience the problem. The queue shows the first two messages as "in-transit" although the lambda logs show that the processing function has errored for both messages minutes ago, but the third message has to wait until the visibility timeout of the first two messages completes

Are you viewing the queue in the SQS management console? That's not a good idea because the console actually grabs messages from the queue and triggers the invisibility timeout. If you avoid looking at the SQS queue in the console, does the Lambda function behave correctly?

Thanks for bearing with me. I checked in the console the SQS overview page (which lists all queues in the account and shows the number of "in flight" messages). I did not poll for messages in the console.

What is your maxReceiveCount for the queue?
